# Installation Stucks At Boot Logo, Ubuntu Studio, New Razer Blade

Tags: boot, ubuntu-studio

I was trying to install Ubuntu Studio 16.10-beta on my Brand new Razer Blade 2016 model with a USB stick burned with dd (I have a linux desktop),
but after I booted into the usb stick and selected a grub entry (doesn't matter which acts the same), it seems it started booting but always stuck at the logo and does not respond to any keys.

So I googled around and none of the solutions work for me, including [this one](https://xipherzero.com/ubuntu-16-04-razer-blade-2016/).

I haven't tried other flavors of ubuntu or even other distros in terms of installation on this laptop, and i'm not interested because Ubuntu Studio is yet the only distro that has a lowlatency kernel built-in also has a jack audio workin' straight outta the box which is very useful to me.

PS. I haven't got enough reputation points to post pics but I will do so as soon as I got enough reputation points.

Comment: So your saying it doesn't go further even with the grub parameters suggested in your link?

Comment: yup. i've been lookin' around and the tty login screen is as far as i can get, i've been able to login with the username "ubuntu-studio" without password, but it will freeze when i try "startx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable kernel modesetting. When in Grub, press E. Add a parameter to the kernel argument line.

To disable KMS add `nomodeset` as a kernel parameter. Along with nomodeset kernel parameter, for Intel graphics card you need to add `i915.modeset=0` and for Nvidia graphics card you need to add `nouveau.modeset=0`. For Nvidia Optimus dual-graphics system, you need to add all the three kernel parameters (i.e. `nomodeset i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0`).

Comment: Thanks a tonnnnn dude! It works! Even though the resolution seemd crunched down a lot, but it works!